# Prove an equation is equal zero in phasor form (exponential)?

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-explanation, polar-coordinates

$$ Ve^{j\omega}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{jk (\frac{2\pi}{n}) } = 0$$

How Can I show that the equation will be zero? is it correct to say the exponential quantity will form a circle using  Euler's Formula and therefore it is zero!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks! first time using the tool I have updated the question

Comment: It's a geometric progression; it's also the sum of the complex numbers representing the vertices of a regular polygon with centre at $0$.

Comment: I want to show that the sigma part is zero so that the equation is correct. hope my question is clear.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to plot the sigma part from n=2 but not sure. also, I was thinking if it completes a circle does that mean in time domain it hits zero so this proves the ewuation